# How to get a download link from a website? (reverse engineering)

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, reverse-engineering, ref

I need a little help, I Have this website:
https://datadashboard.health.gov.il/COVID-19/general

and I Was asked to get the download link of this particular button:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvY3x.png)

And I was unable to do so, Does anybody have a clue on how should I do it?
I tried looking in the elements page and in the page source code, also in the script codes, Can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: There is no HTTP request made when you click that button. This means that the file which is downloaded is dynamically generated by the client-side JS running on that page - as such there is no 'download link' you can subvert.

Comment: I think firstly you should read these articles but I think this is not legal?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping

Comment: Looks like most of the site is client-side js as mentioned by Rory.  I guess there is no easy way to get what you are out after, but you could create a scraper with [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) and from there extract the data needed. Also note that this could be illegal to certant degree.